# I want to print all pairs with given sum k

Tags: python-3.x

```
def printPairs(arr, n, sum):
    for i in range(0, n ):
        for j in range(i + 1, n ):
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum):
                print("(", arr[i], ", ", arr[j], ")", sep = "")




# Driver Code
arr = [1, 5, 7, -1, 5]

n = len(arr)
sum = 6
printPairs(arr, n, sum)
```

Comment: expected output:
(-1, 7)
(1, 5)

Comment: So, what's your question?  If this is from Leetcode, you should add the source link and detail description to make it clear. `maxPairs'?  Your program does not work.  Try this  input [4, 2, 1, 3, 6], target=6

Comment: my question is that, I want to find out pairs in the given array = [1,5,7,-1,5] where pair sum should be 6, I can find out the pairs with above code snippet but i need output as (-1,7) (1,5) ... explanation for the output is that in both the pair the first value is smaller than the next and there should not be any duplicate.Thanks

Comment: Do you try `prefix-sum` or use a mapping `dictionary`?  Is this number of pairs have some constraints?

Comment: Your expected results is strange - should it be like this: `(1,5), (7, -1)` instead?  Based on the position.

Comment: it should be (-1,7) (1,5) and the logic i the first item starts with -1 which is smallest in the both items, so we need to print (-1,7) first and then (1,5), I am sorry for the confusion as it is so weird for me to when i got this problem to solve.

Comment: Then you could just find the result pairs then sort them.  Will show you the simple solution later..

Answer (score 0):

Does this look like it will do the job for you?

```
def printPairs (array, total) :
    used = []
    for number1 in array :
        for number2 in array :
            if number1 + number2 == total and number2 not in used :
                print (f'({number1}, {number2})')
                used.extend ([number1, number2])

test_array = [1, 5, 7, -1, 5]
# test_array = [4, 2, 1, 3, 6]
target = 6
printPairs (test_array, target)
```